# How to remove any remnants of NT from your windows domain?

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain

Even though our domain has been renamed to company.com there still seems to be remnants of COMPANY_NT in different places. For instance, in remote desktop the domain still displays as "COMPANY_NT" and the username would show as "COMPANY_NT\username". It hasn't caused us any problems that we know of but we'd like the NT abolished forever. Anyone know how we might achieve this?

We have 3 server 2012 R2 domain controllers with a server 2012 functional/domain level.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As Shane Madden stated in his answer, an AD domain will always have a NetBIOS name as well as an FQDN.

Comment: Be advised to change the domain name is not an easy task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That `COMPANY_NT` is the NetBIOS name for your domain, which was configured when it was set up - it doesn't actually have any relation to NT legacy cruft, that's just the name that someone picked.

Your domain will need to always have a NetBIOS name - you can't get rid of that.. but if you want, you can change the name with `rendom` so that it no longer says "NT".  See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738208(WS.10).aspx) for how to do that - but, be warned, if you're running Exchange for email then you actually cannot change the NetBIOS domain name.